# В условном операторе выполняются обе ветки // поиск по массиву не работает

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, любой-язык, faq

Я написал поиск по массиву:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    if (array[i] == foo) {
        write('Элемент найден');
    } else {
        write('Элемент не найден');
    }
}
```

Но почему-то в итоге элемент оказывается найденным и ненайденным одновременно. Как такое может быть?

*Проблема стабильно воспроизводится с любыми языками программирования, любыми массивоподобными структурами данных и любыми формами циклов включая jquery each*

Comment: Ради интереса, неужели такие вопросы действительно сколь-нибудь часто попадаются?

Comment: @Fat-Zer я видел четыре.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема в том, что условный оператор выполняется не один раз - а много, по разу на каждую итерацию цикла. И каждый раз выбирается одна из веток, так условный оператор устроен.

Поэтому внутри цикла нельзя делать вывод о том что элемент массива не найден. Этот вывод можно сделать только после того как цикл закончится!

Проще всего исправить алгоритм если кусок кода находится в отдельной подпрограмме (функции) - достаточно добавить выход из функции внутрь "положительной" ветки, тогда любой код после окончания цикла сможет выполниться только если элемент не найден:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    if (array[i] == foo) {
        write('Элемент найден');
        return;
    }
}

write('Элемент не найден');
```

В более сложном случае понадобится дополнительная булева переменная (флаг) чтобы сохранить в ней факт нахождения элемента:

```
bool found = false;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    if (array[i] == foo) {
        write('Элемент найден');
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!found) {
    write('Элемент не найден');
}
```

Иногда бывает что признак "не найдено" можно спрятать в уже существующих переменных и не заводить новую:

```
int foundIndex = -1;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    if (array[i] == foo) {
        foundIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (foundIndex >= 0) {
    write('Элемент найден');
} else {
    write('Элемент не найден');
}
```

Наконец, в языке Python есть еще один способ это сделать - ветка else у цикла:

```
for item in array:
    if item == foo:
        print('Элемент найден')
        break
else:
    print('Элемент не найден')
```

Это работает потому что ветка else у цикла исполняется в том случае если цикл дошел до конца и не был прерван оператором break.