# Зачем мы реализовываем IEquatable<T>, если Equals() есть в Object?

Tags: c#, .net

Разбирая тему обобщений (по Шиелду 4.0), потребовалось написать обобщённый  метод, который вернет логическое значение true, если в массиве содержится некоторое значение. Далее в книге поясняется, что так как T - обобщённый тип, то для сравнения  объектов обобщённого типа  необходимо что бы класс этих объектов реализовывал интерфейс IEquatable с параметром T или IEquatable. Написано так же, что в данных интерфейсах определен метод для сравнения Equals(). Отсюда сразу же несколько вопросов:

Во-первых, почему для сравнения объектов обобщённого типа  нам вообще необходимо реализовывать какие-либо интерфейсы? Метод Equals() относится к методам определённым в Object => есть в каждом объекте. Я понял что для сравнения объектов в данном примере нужно реализовать описанные выше интерфейсы, но я не понял, ПОЧЕМУ это нужно сделать.

Во-вторых, по Шиелду, как я написал выше, для сравнения объектов в обобщённом методе предлагается реализовать Equtable с параметром T или IEqutable. Один параметризирован, другой нет. Вопрос - какой в каком случае необходимо использовать?

Далее Шиелд в своей книге демонстрирует пример метода, который проверяет, находится ли в массиве некоторое значение. Вот этот метод:

```
 public static bool IsIn<T>(T what, T[] obs) where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        foreach(T v in obs)
        {
            if (v.Equals(what))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Тут так же есть два вопроса.

Во-первых, начну с того, что данный метод не работает. Студия выдает ошибку компиляции "Не все ветви метода возвращают значение". Я несколько раз перепроверял написанный код, но ошибка остается. Как это исправить?

Во-вторых, я не уверен, правильно ли я понял, что сигнатура данного метода подразумевает, что в данный метод могут быть переданы только объекты тех типов, которые реализовывают интерфейс IEquatable? Другими словами, если я захочу передать в метод массив каких нибудь студентов, и найти в нём Васю Пупкина, то мой класс студента должен выглядить следующим образом?

```
class Student<T> : IEquatable<T>
{
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {
        //some code for compare
        return false;
    }
}
```

Прошу последовательно ответить на все вопросы. Спасибо

Comment: что значит _для сравнения дженериков_?

Comment: @Grundy исправил, не правильно написал. Этот обобщённый  метод (т.е. дженерик) сравнивает объекты различных типов.

Comment: Насчет метода `IsIn`: в коде не должно быть блока `else`, а должен быть `return false;` после `foreach`-a.

Comment: @Regent, можете написать работающий вариант? Я по разному пробовал, не работает никак

Comment: @АлексейФедотов уже написали в ответе. Но, признаться, я рассчитывал, что по моему сообщению было понятно, что нужно убрать блок `else`, состоящий из 4 строк, и добавить одну строку кода `return false;` после строки с фигурной скобкой, закрывающей тело `foreach`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Интерфейс `IEquatable<>` был придуман для того чтобы избегать лишней упаковки значимых типов при сравнении.

До тех пор, пока все радовались объектам и использовали только их - у метода `object.Equals(object)` особых недостатков не было (лишнее приведение типов особо страшным недостатком не является). Но когда в языке появились обобщенные типы - все стало куда хуже.

Попытка вызвать метод `object.Equals(object other)` для значимого типа приводит к тому, что:

1. нулевой параметр (this) упаковывается и размещается в куче,
2. первый параметр (other) упаковывается и размещается в куче,
3. оба параметра распаковываются обратно и сравниваются,
4. упакованные копии параметров забываются (и в следующий раз упаковка будет происходить заново).

Вообще говоря, обобщенные типы придумали именно для того, чтобы избегать лишних упаковок структур; поэтому необходимость упаковывать их лишь для того чтобы сравнить - катастрофа. Фактически, обобщенная коллекция `System.Collections.Generics.Dictionary<,>` из-за постоянных упаковок может работать даже хуже более старого варианта `System.Collections.Hashtable`.

Потому и был придуман новый интерфейс, который позволяет сравнить два значения без приведения типов (и, как следствие, без упаковки).

---

Теперь про ваш метод. Начну с того, что рекомендация из книги не совсем правильная: в стандартной библиотеке принято другое соглашение относительно подобных методов. Вместо того чтобы требовать реализации `IEquatable<>`, можно воспользоваться классом `EqualityComparer<>`, который внутри использует либо `IEquatable<>`, либо старый метод `object.Equals` если первый недоступен. Кроме того, желательно давать возможность передать в метод любую реализацию `IEqualityComparer<>` (например, для сравнения строк без учета регистра).

Вот так будет правильнее:

```
public static bool IsIn<T>(T what, T[] obs, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    foreach(T v in obs)
    {
        if (comparer.Equals(what, v))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

(Ну и про вторую ошибку в методе я уже писал тут: [В условном операторе выполняются обе ветки // поиск по массиву не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/826277/178779))

С такой реализацией метода его можно использовать как с простыми классами (объекты таких классов сравниваются просто по ссылке):

```
class Student
{
    public string Name;
    public string Surname;
}
```

так и с более продвинутыми:

```
sealed class Student : IEquatable<Student>
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly string Surname;

    public Student(string name, string surname)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other) => Equals(other as Student);
    public bool Equals(Student other) 
    {
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (Name != other.Name) return false;
        if (Surname!= other.Surname) return false;
        return true;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked 
        {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/4340086
            int hash = 2166136261;
            hash = (16777619 * hash) ^ (Name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
            hash = (16777619 * hash) ^ (Surname?.GetHashCode() ?? 0);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`Equals(object obj)` появился в .NET в самом начале, а тогда еще не было дженериков. До введения дженериков в .NET 2.0, переопределение метода `Equals(object obj)` в большинстве случаев выглядело приблизительно так:

```
public bool override Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (obj is MyClass)
    {
        MyClass other = (MyClass)obj;
        // сравниваем this и other
    }
    return false;
}
```

Получается, в большинстве случаев, объекты разных типов не могут быть равны. Что бы упростить жизнь, придумали интерфейс `IEquatable<T>`, в котором можно сразу сравнивать 2 объекта, без проверок их типов (что тоже занимает некоторое время).

По-хорошему теперь вы должны реализовать `IEquatable<T>` для всех классов, которые можно сравнивать. При этом вы должны не забывать про переопределение старого `Equals`, для совместимости. Можно делать например вот так:

```
public bool override Equals(object obj)
{
    return Equals(obj as MyClass);
}

public bool Equals(MyClass other)
{
    if (other== null)
        return false;
    // сравниваем объекты
}
```

Comment: В каких случаях нужно использовать параметризированный вариант IEqutable, а в каких обычный?

Comment: @АлексейФедотов а разве существует обычный `IEquatable`?

Comment: Я ошибся. По Шиелду так: "Для сравнения двух объектов параметра обобщенного типа они должны реализовывать
интерфейс IComparable или IComparable<T> и/или интерфейс IEquatable<T>."
Т.е. получается, даже если у меня есть не обобщённый класс Person например, что бы его сравнивать в обобщённом методе, мне придется делать из него дженерик? Вот так? class Person<T> : IEquatable<T>

Comment: @АлексейФедотов Нет, не придется. Вы делаете так: `class Person : IEquatable<Person>`

Comment: Другими словами, разрабатывая свой класс, я могу руководствоваться следующим правилом: Если мой класс может быть сравнен в обобщённом методе, то разрабатываю следующим образом: class Person : IEquatable<Person>. Если мой класс не будет сравниваться в обобщенном методе, то достаточно будет только override Equals() от Object. Верно?

Comment: @АлексейФедотов да, верно. Только если вы сделали `Equals` от `Object`, то все равно лучше реализовать `IEquatable<T>`. В таком случае тот, кто использует ваш класс, понимает, что его можна сравнивать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78876/discussion-between---and-zergatul).

Answer (score 4):

Насчет "Не все ветви метода возвращают значение": если obs пустой, то код внутри `foreach` никогда не выполнится, следовательно метод не встретит ни одного оператора return. поэтому ошибка.

Насколько я понимаю, код метода должен быть таким:

```
public static bool IsIn<T>(T what, T[] obs) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    foreach(T v in obs)
    {
        if (v.Equals(what))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Да, сигнатура данного метода подразумевает, что в данный метод могут быть переданы только объекты тех типов, которые реализовывают интерфейс IEquatable.

Comment: разве данный синтаксис не значит "пройди по всем элементам массива, если совпало верни true, после цикла все равно верни false"? False же будет возвращен в любом случае, разве нет? Такого же быть вроде как не должно. Так же по прежнему не понятно, почему мы вообще реализовываем данные интерфейсы, если метод Equals() определен в Object. Зачем реализовывать IEqutable? И в каких случаях реализовываем параметризированный вариант, а в каких обычный?

Comment: @АлексейФедотов, _False же будет возвращен в любом случае, разве нет?_ только в случае если в процессе прохода по коллекции ничего не совпало. Если совпало - происходит сразу выход из функции с возвратом `true`

Comment: @АлексейФедотов, нет. return прерывает выполнение данного метода и возвращает вышестоящему указанное значение. после выполнения return в методе уже ничего выполняться не будет.

Comment: "Зачем реализовывать IEqutable?" хороший вопрос. Я подозреваю что это результат исторического развития языка и платформы .net - то что было правильным в первых версиях становится неактуальным грузом в последующих версиях. На самом деле, я и сам бы почитал хорошие размышления на эту тему.

Comment: интерфейсы в .NET появились гораздо позже, чем Object.Equals(). Пока интерфейсов не было, не было другого способа, кроме как унаследоваться от Object и перекрыть его Equals. С появлением интерфейсов другой способ появился. Не сказать, что интерфейсы вводились именно для этой задачи ))) Просто так получилось - интерфейсы гораздо более мощный инструмент, нежели единый класс в корне иерархии.